# Fixing Merge Conflicts with Git Rebase and Exporting

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I've run into a few merge conflicts with git rebase.

My question is, if I fix the conflicts, do I then do something like this:

```
git add files
git commit "fixed merge conflicts"
```

then continue with

```
git rebase --continue
```

My other question is if I mess up, can I do

```
git rebase --abort
```

and will that remove all the commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50730290/fixing-merge-conflicts-with-git-rebase-and-exporting#comment88468479_50730379) on [jready's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50730379/1256452), your real question is whether you should save your original chain of commits somewhere / somehow.

Rebase, at a sort of fundamental level, works by copying (because commits can never be changed—this includes their backwards-looking links).  Branch names simply point to some specific commit.  If we draw the commits as nodes in a graph, what we have looks like this:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- origin/whatever
         \
          J--K--L   <-- your-branch
```

If you run `git checkout your-branch && git rebase origin/whatever`, Git must *copy* commit `J`, by turning it into a set of changes vs its parent `G`, and apply those changes to commit `I` (where `origin/whatever` points).  Having copied `J` to `J'`, it then tries to copy `K` to a new commit `K'`, and so on.  The eventual result, after you resolve any conflicts but before Git "peels the name off" commit `L`, is:

```
                J'-K'-L'  <-- HEAD
               /
...--F--G--H--I   <-- origin/whatever
         \
          J--K--L   <-- your-branch
```

The very last step of `git rebase` is to remove the name `your-branch` from where it is pasted right now, pointing to commit `L`, and make it point instead to commit `L'`—the last copy that rebase made:

```
                J'-K'-L'  <-- your-branch (HEAD)
               /
...--F--G--H--I   <-- origin/whatever
         \
          J--K--L   [abandoned]
```

If you use `git rebase --abort` instead of continuing, Git just abandons the copied chain instead, leaving the name `your-branch` still pointing to `L`:

```
                J'-K'-L'  [abandoned]
               /
...--F--G--H--I   <-- origin/whatever
         \
          J--K--L   <-- your-branch (HEAD)
```

Before you start the rebase, or any time in the middle of the rebase when `your-branch` still points to commit `L`, you can add a new name to remember the raw hash ID of commit `L`:

```
                J'-K'  <-- HEAD
               /
...--F--G--H--I   <-- origin/whatever
         \
          J--K--L   <-- your-branch, extra-name
```

which you might do with `git branch extra-name your-branch` for instance.  That way, after you finish the rebase, assuming you do finish it, you end up with:

```
                J'-K'-L'  <-- your-branch (HEAD)
               /
...--F--G--H--I   <-- origin/whatever
         \
          J--K--L   <-- extra-name
```

You don't *have* to do this, because secretly, `git rebase` sets up a special name, `ORIG_HEAD`, to remember where your branch name was before it yanked it off `L` and pasted it onto `L'`.  But the name `ORIG_HEAD` will be overwritten by whatever other Git command you use later (maybe another rebase) that yanks a label around like this, so that's sort of a short-term stop-gap you can use to recover if you don't like the result.

Your Git also records, in something called the *reflog* for the branch, the previous value of the branch name, i.e., the fact that `your-branch` used to point to commit `L` instead of `L'`.  These reflog entries last for 30 or 90 days.<sup>1</sup>  They're not the easiest things to use, though:

```
git reflog your-branch
```

will spill out all of them, but what you get is the one-line summary you used in each commit, and when you use `git rebase` you generally copy the original one-line summary from commit `L` to commit `L'`, so it can be hard to tell which one is which.

Still, some combination of `ORIG_HEAD` and the reflogs will usually let you recover without an extra name.  Use the extra name if it makes you more comfortable.  I do it a lot: if I am working on `feature/X`, and need to rebase, I create `feature/X.0` and then rebase.  My original series of commits are now available as the dot-zero version.  A few days later, if I need to do another rebase, I create `feature/X.1` and then rebase.  So `feature/X` is the latest, and `feature/X.<number>` is the older one, with more older ones remaining until I collect them up and toss them out myself.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, the ones that expire in 30 days are using the `expireUnreachable` time: these are commits that are not *reachable* from the current value of the reference.  Rebase generally makes this kind of reference, so the default 30 day expiration is the one you should concentrate on.

(Reflog entries that *are* reachable get the 90 day default.)

Comment: Right so if i did a skip did I essentially overwrite all my commits over the other branch? I feel extremely dumb for making a tantamount mistake on my branch :(

Comment: You have not *overwritten* anything. Rebase is copying each commit, one at a time, and when it stops and says "I failed to copy the one I'm trying to copy" and you say `--skip` you are telling rebase: *don't copy that one particular commit, go on and copy the rest though, unless you have to stop again and I say skip again.* So when you're done and realize that this was all wrong, you can use `ORIG_HEAD` or the reflog entry to recover, using `git reset --hard`.

Comment: I know what i did wrong, I was using reflog without referencing my particular branch, hence why I couldn't rebase. THANK YOU

Comment: Just remember that commits in Git are immutable; they will never change under any circumstance*. Git will always create new commits for any operation where it appears that Git has altered commits. If you examine the SHA-1 for the commits you will actually see this. Git will also never explicitly remove commits except part of its garbage collection process, which @torek mentioned.
Your commits will be safe throughout the entire `rebase` process :)

Answer (score 0):

`git rebase --abort` will just back out of the rebase entirely, essentially reverting your repository back to the point in time right before you started the `rebase`. The only commits that are lost will be the brand new commits that `git rebase` had created (since `git rebase` *replays* your original commits, thus forming new commits).

The original commits are never touched regardless of whether you abort or not.

Comment: oh ok so it will just remove the commits that I'm performing with the merge? I'm just wondering if I should make another branch and do a rebase on that just in case I mess up